# cin a pointer reference to a struct

Tags: c++

I am using cin and cout in my program. I starts off fine because it is not executing any of the functions, but after you type your name, it throws an exception in the iostream library. wondering if it is a problem with using cin through refrence.`

```
    // linkedlists.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct person {
    string name;
    int age;
    struct person* next;
};
person *head = NULL;
int length() {
    int count = 0;
    person *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
void printlist() {
    person *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL){
        cout << "Name: " << current->name << "    Age: " << current->age << "\n";
        current = current->next;
    }
}
void insert() {
//  int choice;
    person *newNode = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(person));
    //cout << "Press 1 to insert at beginning of list.\n";
    //cin >> choice;
//  switch (choice) {
    //case 1:

    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    cout << "What is this person's name?\n";
    cin >> newNode->name;
    cout << "\nWhat is the age of " << newNode->name << "?";
    cin >> newNode->age;
    cout << "The current list of people is " << length() << " long.\n";
    printlist();
}
void menu() {
    int choice;
    cout << "Welcome to the person recorder! ";
    bool inloop = true;
    while (inloop) {
        cout << "Press 1 to add more entries. Press 2 to print the entire list. Press 3 to exit the program.\n";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            insert();
        case 2:
            printlist();
        case 3:
            inloop = false;
        }
    }
}
/*void change(person* human) {
    string temp_name;
    int temp_age;
    cout << "What is this person's name?\n";
    cin >> temp_name;
    cout << "\nWhat is this person's age?\n";
    cin >> temp_age;
    human->name = temp_name;
    human->age = temp_age;
}
*/
int main()
{
    menu();
}
```

using visual studio 2015, am a noob to c/c++ and trying to make a linked list.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ instead of `new`? That could be one of your problems because `malloc` only allocates memory, it doesn't construct object (call constructors).

Comment: `person *newNode = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(person));` Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by accessing the object before its lifetime has started (`person`'s constructor never ran). Forget about `malloc` in C++ code, just make it `person *newNode = new person;`

Comment: There is no such language as c/c++ - you seem to be using elements of both, but that doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your allocation of `person`:

```
person *newNode = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(person));
```

This will allocate memory on the heap for an instance of `person`, but it will not call the constructor of `person` and any of it's members. This does not matter for `age` and `next` since they are primitive types, but `name` is an `std::string`, which has a constructor that needs to be called for it to function properly.

In C++ you create instances of objects using the keyword `new`.

```
person *newNode = new person;
```

This will create a new instance of person, and also call its constructor, which will initialize `name` properly.

Once you are done with the instance of person, you will have use the keyword `delete` to clean it up.

```
delete newNode;
```

Similar to the difference between `malloc` and `new`, `delete` will `free` the memory, but also call the destructor, which is used by `name` to clean up any resources it may have allocated to store the string.

Comment: thanks! I forgot to not use Malloc, with new it is working